# Popup on wrong browser

Tags: browser

I've created my own browser. But when I click on a button to enter a browser game a window should show up with the game, it does but on "Internet Explorer" Not my browser. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set it up to be your default browser.

Comment: Oh, how do I add a function to my browser so I can make it to my default?

Comment: I think you can do it trough (if you are using Windows 7) Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Default Programs -> Set Default Program ...and select your browser.

Comment: Isnt it any way to make my browser show a window that says "Make Default Browser (YES) (NO)"

Comment: there must be you just have to make it though and i have no idea what platform or language were you using to make it.

Answer (score 0):

To change the default program in Windows 7 go to

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Default Programs\Set Associations

Scroll down to the bottom, protocols

Find https and https and click on change program... to change it to your program.

or programmatically alter the registry.  The keys that contains the programs to open are

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\ftp\UserChoice
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice
```

The value to change is the Progid value

This needs to match what is in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

If we examine ChromeHTML it has the following

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="Chrome HTML Document"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\Edit]
@="&Edit"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\Edit\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\msohtmed.exe\" %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" -- \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\Print]
@="&Print"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\Print\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\msohtmed.exe\" /p %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\ShellEx\IconHandler]
@="{42042206-2D85-11D3-8CFF-005004838597}"
```

So, I simply create the same things with replacing ChromeHTML with the name of my program for an example, AwesomeBrowser, and recreate these keys with AwesomeBrowser in place of Chrome and the open path to AwesomeBrowser.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AwesomeBrowser]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="Chrome HTML Document"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AwesomeBrowser\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AwesomeBrowser\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AwesomeBrowser\shell\Edit]
@="&Edit"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AwesomeBrowser\shell\Edit\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\msohtmed.exe\" %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AwesomeBrowser\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AwesomeBrowser\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AwesomeBrowser\\AwesomeBrowser.exe\" -- \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AwesomeBrowser\shell\Print]
@="&Print"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AwesomeBrowser\shell\Print\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\msohtmed.exe\" /p %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AwesomeBrowser\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AwesomeBrowser\ShellEx\IconHandler]
@="{42042206-2D85-11D3-8CFF-005004838597}"
```

Then set the Progid values to AwesomeBrowser

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice]
"Progid"="AwesomeBrowser"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice]
"Progid"="AwesomeBrowser"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\ftp\UserChoice]
"Progid"="AwesomeBrowser"
```